# ElastAlert splits the field

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

I am using ElastAlert to notify my consumers if an error occurs in past 10 mins. I want to send list of errors which occurred. But the items in the list are split into two if there is hyphen ('-') present in errorCode

This is result I want

```
errorCode:
error1: 10
error-place-2: 15
error-new-place-3: 20
```

This is result I am getting

```
erorrCode:
error1: 10
error: 35
place: 35
2: 15
new: 20
3: 20
```

Is there a way to get the desired results?

Update - adding results of index mappings

```
{  
"indexdate":{    
      "mappings":{  
         "app_log":{  
            "properties":{  
         },
         "transaction_log":{  
            "properties":{  
               "@timestamp":{  
                  "type":"date",
                  "format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
               },
               "other":{
               },
               "errorCode":{  
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "other":{
               },
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to make sure that your `errorCode` field is `not_analyzed`as it doesn't seem to be the case, hence why your error codes are split.

Comment: Where do I need to set `errorCode` field as `not_analyzed`?

Comment: In your mapping. How does it look like right now? Run this `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your-index/` and replace `your-index` the real index name. Update your question with the result you get.

Comment: I have mappings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your `errorCode` field is `not_analyzed` as it doesn't seem to be the case, hence why your error codes are split.

You can modify your mapping like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/indexdate/_mapping/transaction_log -d '{
   "properties": {
      "errorCode":{  
         "type":"string",
         "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

After making this change, you need to reindex your data in order to populate the `errorCode.raw` field.

Then you'll need to use `errorCode.raw` in your ElastAlert config instead of `errorCode`

Comment: thanks a lot. Will try it out and check if it works.